# Merge multiple dynamic arrays into a single array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sorry for the confusing title, I have a problem where I have 3 dynamic arrays (can be empty):

```
const titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"]
const subtitles = ["Subtitle 1", "Subtitle 2"]
const contents = ["Content 1"]
```

and I need to change them into:

```
const newArr = [
    { title: "Title 1", subtitle: "Subtitle 1", content: "Content 1" },
    { title: "Title 2", subtitle: "Subtitle 2" },
    { title: "Title 3" }
]
```

My attempt to solve this:

```
const newState = []

titles.map((titleItem, index) => { newState[index] = { title: titleItem } });
subtitles.map((subtitleItem, index) => { newState[index] = { subtitle: subtitleItem } });
contents.map((contentItem, index) => { newState[index] = { content: contentItem } });
```

but sadly, this overwrites the newState for every map.

Comment: So the labels are the names of the variables, and they are just assigned after each other? What have you tried till now and where are you stuck?

Comment: This should basically be a `for` loop, where the limit is the length of the longest array. For each property in the object, check whether the current index is less than the length of the corresponding array.

Comment: yes, the arrays aren't static, could also be possible to have an empty array for any one of them, which is the tricky part :/

Comment: Loop through the array with biggest `length` and create the output.

Comment: Seems like an interview question of some sort, and an extremely easy one at that.  Will all data be contiguous or can gaps occur anywhere.  It'd be impossible if you were expected to match ["1", "2", "3"] to ["1", "3"] and ["2"] but you've only shown us one possible way the arrays could be arranged (["1", "2", "3"], ["1", "2"], ["1"]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would store the input as an object, where the property names are what you have as variable names, then here is one way to do it:

```js
function zip(arg) {
    return Object.entries(arg).reduce( (acc, [k, arr]) => {
        arr.forEach( (v, i) => (acc[i] = acc[i] || {})[k] = v );
        return acc;
    }, []);
}

const result = zip({ 
    title: ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"],
    subtitle: ["Subtitle 1", "Subtitle 2"],
    content: ["Content 1"]
});

console.log(result);
```

This allows for other configurations where you would have more than 3 arrays to merge, with potentially different names.

Answer (score 0):

Could be solved this way, for not performance-critical code I find usage of maps cleaner.

```js
let titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"]
let subtitles = ["Subtitle 1", "Subtitle 2"]
let contents = ["Content 1"]

const maxLength = Math.max(titles.length, subtitles.length, contents.length);

const resultWithUndefined = Array(maxLength).fill(null)
  .map((_,i) => [titles[i], subtitles[i], contents[i]])
  .map(([title, subtitle, content]) => ({title, subtitle, content}));

console.log(resultWithUndefined)

const resultClean = Array(maxLength).fill(null)
  .map((_,i) => [titles[i], subtitles[i], contents[i]])
  .map(([title, subtitle, content]) => 
    Object.assign({},
      typeof title === "undefined" ? {} : {title},
      typeof subtitle === "undefined" ? {} : {subtitle},
      typeof content === "undefined" ? {} : {content},
    ));
    
console.log(resultClean)
```